# what is this error in PSPICE with IR2113

Tags: mosfet, driver, buck, mosfet-driver, pspice

I want drive a buck converter with bootstrap technique. but this circuit does not work!
[image]

Comment: Try putting an earth on the negative end of V4 and see what happens. At the moment it looks floating to me and I don't think it would properly work if you built it without that cross-connection to the driver.

Comment: The error is telling you the step size is too small. Fix it.

Comment: Did you edit this to be a completely different controller now? Looks nothing like the circuit I initially based my answer on. And the PSPICE error is missing?

Answer (score 1):

The IR2118 doesn't seem to be hooked up correctly. Its floating high-side bootstrap pin (VB) isn't actually connected to anything -- it should be hooked up to at the least a capacitor to the VS pin, and the application diagram calls for an external diode connecting VCC to that node as well:

[image: IR2117/IR2118 annotated.]

Right now, it has no ability to generate the boosted drive voltage for your transistor because the bootstrap supply isn't working / isn't connected correctly. Since you are using a N-channel enhancement mode device, it requires a positive VGS to function. The IR2118 driver has a floating pin (VB) which supplies the positive voltage to the MOSFET, referenced against whatever the source of the transistor is connected too:

[image: Block diagram.]

In the typical connection diagram, thanks to the diode between VCC and VB, it's creating a simple voltage multiplier to generate the voltage needed to drive the transistor. You could also hook up some arbitrary high-voltage supply to VB.